# Moodle/Drupal single sign on using OAuth or ldap

Tags: drupal, oauth, ldap, single-sign-on, moodle

**I want to create a way for Moodle users to automatically login to a Drupal site using OAuth or ldap.**

How can this be done..

Is there any well written modules or api around there?

Any help will be thankful and grateful?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: LDAP is not an alternative to OAuth. They're two complete different things. So, that can't be an "or" in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Have you already had a look to this integration mechanism?

http://drupal.org/project/moodle

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your Drupal site with Moodle using any of the 2 protocols (OAuth or LDAP). If you are looking for some plugins or module to do so, you can check out the [Drupal OAuth Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth_login_oauth2) module for OAuth and also the [Drupal LDAP module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap_auth) (if you are looking for LDAP)